# Increment a value after defining a byte with db in Assembly Level Proramming

Tags: assembly, nasm

Hi could someone help me out with this? I'm new to assembly level programming.

In my alp code, I have defined a byte with the code:

```
count db 0
```

In another part of the program I'm trying to fetch the value into the ah register and adding 1 to it like so:

```
mov ah,count
add ah,1
```

Now, how do I update the memory location recognized by **count** with the new and incremented value in the **ah** register so that I can use it as a counter for looping or any other purposes?

Comment: Can't you just `mov` it back?

Comment: Does mov work that way?
I mean does
mov _register_name_,_memory_loc_
work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mov ah, count` isn't going to work. In Nasm syntax, that would try to move the address of `count` into ah... and it won't fit. You want "[contents]".

```
mov ah, [count]
inc ah
mov [count], ah
```

You could also...

```
inc byte [count]
; and perhaps...
cmp byte [count], MAXCOUNT
jb looptop
```

(with `MAXCOUNT` and `looptop` defined, of course) It's faster to work with registers than with memory, but you can do either. As Mat suggests, don't hesitate to "try it"!

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a ton! I didn't know, the byte address have to be enclosed in [] for the actual content/value to be fetched!